# Cast int to enum strings in Typescript

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, enums

I get from a RESTful Service the following data:

```
[
  {
    "id": 42,
    "type": 0,
    "name": "Piety was here",
    "description": "Bacon is tasty, tofu not, ain't nobody like me, cause i'm hot...",
  }...
```

And I'm mapping with this class:

```
export enum Type {
  Info,
  Warning,
  Error,
  Fatal,
}


export class Message{
  public id: number;
  public type: Type:
  public name: string;
  public description: string;
}
```

But when I access 'type' in Angular2 I get only a int value. But I'd like to get a string value.

e.g:

```
'message.type=0'
{{message.type}} => should be Info
'message.type=1'
{{message.type}} => should be Warning
```

Comment: Is this a compile-time problem or a runtime problem?

Comment: It compiles and runs fine. For `{{message.type}]` I get `0` but I want to get `Info`.

Answer (score 129, accepted):

Enums in TypeScript are numbers at runtime, so `message.type` will be `0`, `1`, `2` or `3`.

To get the string value, you need to pass that number into the enum as an index:

```
Type[0] // "Info"
```

So, in your example, you'll need to do this:

```
Type[message.type] // "Info" when message.type is 0
```

[Docs](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/enums.html)

Comment: How can I do that? I'm mapping like this right now:
`(response => response.json() as Message[]`

Comment: Import `Type` into your file, and rather than doing `message.type` to get the value, do `Type[message.type]`. You do this where you want the string value

Comment: Unfortunately, `Type` will not be available inside a template, unless you add it as a property to the component class as `public Type = Type;`.

Comment: Can anyone tell me why if i do Type[message.type] in my case, in debugger I see an error because Type is undefined (it's imported properly to this .ts file)?

Answer (score 64):

Enums in TypeScript are objects at runtime that have properties that go from `int -> string` and from `string -> int` for all possible values.

To access the string value you will need to call:

```
Type[0] // "Info"
```

Make sure that you are passing the correct type into the property accessor though because chained calls can result in the following:

```
Type[Type.Info] // "Info"
Type[Type[Type.Info]] // 0
Type["Info"] // 0
Type[0] // "Info"
```

Comment: How to check if a number is part of the enum, f.x. check for number 3000 before returning Type[3000]?

Comment: @gajo357 You can use the `in` operator to test if 3000, or any value/key exists in the enum. Example `const has3000 = 3000 in Type`

Answer (score 3):

**This is how enum works in the typescript:**

```
   enum PrintMedia {
      Newspaper = 1,
      Newsletter,
      Magazine,
      Book
    }

  PrintMedia.Magazine;            // returns  3
  PrintMedia["Magazine"];         // returns  3
  PrintMedia[3];                  // returns  Magazine
  PrintMedia[PrintMedia.Magazine];// returns  Magazine
```

Answer (score 2):

I think with

```
{{message.type}}
```

you just get the mapped value and not the enum.
Please try following code.

```
{{TYPE[message.type]}}
```