# Angular 5 convert Enum int to string

Tags: angular, angular2-template, angular5

I would like to display my enum as a string but it display as a number.

I am receiving a json object from a web service and mapping it to my typescript object

```
getProperties(): Observable<Property[]> {
    return this.http.get<Property[]>(this.getallagentsproperties + '1');
}

export enum LetType {
    Notspecified = 0,
    LongTerm = 1,
    ShortTerm = 2,
    Commercial = 4
}

export class Property {
    ...other stuff...
    letType: LetType;
    ...other stuff...
}
```

My component makes the call and adds it to the relevant property

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { Property } from './Property';
import { PropertyService } from '../properties.service';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-properties',
  templateUrl: './properties.component.html',
})

export class PropertiesComponent implements OnInit {
  properties: Property[];
  constructor(private propertyService: PropertyService) { }
  ngOnInit() {
    this.getProperties()
  }
  getProperties(): void {
    this.propertyService.getProperties()
        .subscribe(p => this.properties = p);
  }
}
```

When I display `{{property.letType}}` in my template is displays:

`4` I want it to display Commercial

I have tried to follow the answer found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42299257/cast-int-to-enum-strings-in-typescript#_=_) in my template I added

```
{{LetType[property.letType]}}
```

and in my Componant I added

```
LetType = this.LetType;
```

but I always get the below error in the console

> Cannot read property '4' of undefined

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: You can't refer to the enum directly in your template, need to bridge. See the answer of this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37741010/angular2-access-global-variables-from-html-template

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Thanks to @Harry Ninh comment I was able to solve my issue.

`{{property.letType}}` displayed `0` I wanted it display `My Enum Value`

**note:** I did not ask for the split casing in my question but I have provided that here as I feel many people who are displaying an enum as a string value could find it useful

Step 1 Add required enum (LetType in my case) to your component

```
import { Component, OnInit, Type } from '@angular/core';
import { Property, LetType} from './Property';
import { PropertyService } from '../properties.service';

@Component({
    selector: 'app-properties',
    templateUrl: './properties.component.html',
})
export class PropertiesComponent implements OnInit {

    properties: Property[];
    LetType = LetType;

    constructor(private propertyService: PropertyService) { }

    ngOnInit() {
        this.getProperties();
    }

    getProperties(): void {
        this.propertyService.getProperties()
            .subscribe(p => this.properties = p);
    }
}
```

step 2 create custom pipe to convert your number to a string

```
import { Pipe, PipeTransform } from '@angular/core';

@Pipe({
  name: 'eNumAsString'
})

export class ENumAsStringPipe implements PipeTransform {
    transform(value: number, enumType: any): any {
        return enumType[value].split(/(?=[A-Z])/).join().replace(",", " ");;
    }
}
```

Step 3 add your pipe to the table

```
...other html table tags...
    <td>{{property.letType | eNumAsString:LetType}}</td>
...other html table tags...
```

Comment: If I don't apply the pipe I get an empty combo box

Answer (score 26):

You don't need to create a pipe here. Here is my answer.

let-type.enum.ts

```
export enum LetType{
  Type1 = 1,
  Type2 = 2,
  Type3 = 3,
  Type4 = 4
}
```

property.model.ts

```
export interface Property{
   ...other stuff...
   letType: LetType;
   ...other stuff...
}
```

properties.component.ts

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { Property} from './property.model';
import { LetType} from './let-type.enum';
import { PropertyService } from '../properties.service';

@Component({
   selector: 'app-properties',
   templateUrl: './properties.component.html',
})
export class PropertiesComponent implements OnInit {

  properties: Property[] = [];
  LetType = LetType;

  constructor(private propertyService: PropertyService) { }

  ngOnInit() {
     this.getProperties();
  }

  getProperties() {
    this.propertyService.getProperties().subscribe(result => {
         this.properties = result
    });
  }
}
```

Then in your html

```
<ng-container matColumnDef="columnName">
   <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef >Types</th>
   <td  mat-cell *matCellDef="let element">{{LetType[element.letType]}}</td>
</ng-container>
```

Answer (score 9):

You can do this without pipe:

```
LetType : typeof 
LetType = LetType ;
```

and in the html page:

```
<td  mat-cell *matCellDef="let element">{{LetType[element.letType]}}</td>
```

as before.