# TypeScript: Get enum item by number

Tags: typescript, enums

EDIT: I stumbled upon this problem, because I made a wrong assumption. It is thus not a *good* question but the accepted answer explains my mistake well. I thus consider it still worth being archived here.

---

I have:

```
enum TimePeriod {
    Custom = 0,
    LastWeek = 1,
}
```

I also have a drop down HTML element with values 0 or 1, depending on what the user chose (Custom or LastWeek). I want a simple `if (val === TimePeriod.Custom)`, but I cannot figure out what `val` should be.

I understand that:

```
const val = $("#TimePeriod").val() as number;
```

will not work (ie. above `if` always false), **because `val` is a number** and not a `TimePeriod`

**EDIT: This is the wrong assumption!**

```
const val = $("#TimePeriod").val() as TimePeriod;
```

will not work, either, because the `as TimePeriod`-part is lost then it is converted to JS. It is thus exactly the same as the first try.

Also tried:

```
const val = TimePeriod[$("#TimePeriod").val() as number];
```

But then `val` is a string, e.g. `"Custom"`

What `val` must actually be is an instance of a enum value, e.g. `TimePerios.Custom`. But how do I obtain it dynamically having only number `0`?

I read [Cast int to enum strings in Typescript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42299257/cast-int-to-enum-strings-in-typescript) and even [How do I convert a string to enum in TypeScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17380845/how-do-i-convert-a-string-to-enum-in-typescript) but it does not help.

Comment: `as number` also doesn’t do anything at runtime.  At runtime, `val` Is probably a string and your enum is a number.  To compare them you should actually convert `val` to a number, via some method like prefixing `+` or `Number.valueOf()` or something

Comment: "val is probably a string and your enum is a number" --> Yes, that was it! If you write an answer I can give you credits for it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue is that [type assertions](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/basic-types.html#type-assertions) (`value as Type`) have no runtime effect at all; they are just a way of telling the compiler the type of a value when the compiler is unable to infer or verify that for itself.  If you use a type assertion you need to be careful that you  are not lying to the compiler, and any problems you face at at runtime due to an erroneous assertion are your responsibility to deal with.

Without a type assertion, the following line:

```
const val = $("#TimePeriod").val();
```

yields a `val` of the this type:

```
// const val: string | number | string[] | undefined
```

So, when you say

```
const val = $("#TimePeriod").val() as number;
```

you are claiming that you know `val` will be a `number` at runtime, even though all the compiler knows is that it is either a `number` or a `string`, or an array of `string`, or maybe even `undefined`.  Do you know that `val` will be a `number`?  And if so, how?

My expectation is that `.val()` generally produces a `string`, and that it would pretty much never be a `number` (I guess it [can maybe happen]?([How can val() return Number?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9227268/how-can-val-return-number))).  One way to be sure that you end up with a `number` is to explicitly [convert it to one at runtime](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number):

```
const val = Number($("#TimePeriod").val()); // number
```

---

At that point you can directly compare with `TimePeriod` members.  At runtime, values like `TimePeriod.Custom` are just `number`s, as per the documentation of [numeric enums](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/enums.html#numeric-enums):

```
console.log(TimePeriod.Custom); // 0
console.log(typeof TimePeriod.Custom); // number
```

So you can do something like:

```
switch (val) {
  case TimePeriod.Custom: {
    console.log("custom!")
  }
  case TimePeriod.LastWeek: {
    console.log("last week!")
  }
  default: {
    console.log("who knows?")
  }
}
```

which should work.

---

Okay, hope that helps.  Good luck!

[Link to code](http://www.typescriptlang.org/play/?noImplicitAny=false#code/JYWwDg9gTgLgBAKjgQwM5wCRwGZQiOAIgCsBHAVwFMoBPQgbgChHKA7cggFVEoAVrgEACZwA3oziS4AYXKoY+OAF44ABgA0EqQBk0MAOqVKAa2VwAjJoC+zAMYRWqCABtKAOmcQA5gApuIPgFhN1l5fABKejgAemi1RntHF3dPXxgaMEoIbDh-QKhBIRC5BRBImLj2EAAjajsHeTgAN2RnMwA5DlqoHwwfQgBiPP4C4UJwtxbnH3Dw5lQAd2AYWwALOB8p8LEtWzRKXJ4RwuKwkAAuHak4RKdXD29+2xL8AEJxrRtJPdQD4aCirp5IYTJdxNdbskHr5CM49HAFkZjO85pIvnAhJRsMhyM4YGCtN8GlDUv0FqsIHBjKwIAtUAB+D5oxhWIA)